# Intercepting/analyzing traffic from a google chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I would like to write a google chrome extension to intercept http traffic and to create graphs similar to how network tab does it. Is there API available to do this? I found there's WebRequest API: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/experimental.webRequest.html but it says it is still in experimental stage, I wonder how stable it is at this point and if there're any good samples that use it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Experimental is just that. Experimental. It could have breaking changes in an release of chrome. The other downsides of experimental is only being available in the dev channel of Chrome (or more unstable such as canary), extensions using experimental can not be uploaded to the Web Store, and user have to have the enable experimental extensions flag.

If you still want to use the experimental webRequest API I wrote a simple example in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447082/using-chrome-experimental-webrequest-api-to-change-loaded-file/6462991#6462991).