# Simple forwarding using Google Chrome webRequest API

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, webrequest, forwarding

I am attempting to create a Chrome extension to help me understand Chrome's [webRequest](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/webRequest.html) API by replicating what is done with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447082/using-chrome-experimental-webrequest-api-to-change-loaded-file) but without the experimental portion of the namespace, which is no longer needed since webRequest is now in Chrome's trunk.

In my background page I have the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <script>
function interceptRequest(request) {
    return { redirectUrl: 'http://www.yahoo.com' }
}
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(interceptRequest, { urls: ['*://*.google.com/*'] }, ['blocking']);
  </script>
  </head><body></body>
</html>
```

In my manifest file I have:

```
{
  "name": "My Extension",
  "version": "0.1",
  "background_page": "background.html",
  "permissions" : [
     "webRequest",
     "webRequestBlocking",
     "*://*/*"
  ]
}
```

Based on the previously asked question, I should be forwarded to http://www.yahoo.com when I access https://www.google.com and my extension is loaded, however, https://www.google.com loads without any forwarding effect. What do I need to do in order to simply forward a user from one URI to another using the webRequest API in Chrome?

Comment: That's odd. The only I can think of is to make sure you aren't loading any synchronous XHR's or including any script tags from online resources in your background page, from the Chrome docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your url matching pattern isn't correct. You simply need to add a trailing slash:

```
{urls: ['https://www.google.com/']}
```

Alternatively, you could use:
   **'*://www.google.com/'** to match all protocols, **'*://www.google.com/*'** to match beyond just the domain, and **'*://*.google.com/*'** to match all subdomains, protocols and  paths, etc.

See:
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/match_patterns.html

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but non of these solutions caused the browser to be forwarded to Yahoo. Do you see anything else wrong with the above or perhaps something I didn't include?

Comment: I created an extension with your code and it is working fine for me after putting a trailing slash in the `urls` field as described in my comment above. The only thing I notice is `content_scripts` in your manifest file... do you have a `content.js` file? You don't need it for this functionality. Are all your paths correct (background.html and content.js are in the root of your extension)? Also, wrap `<script>...</script>` tags around your JS code in your background.html (I assumed it was wrapped--it's an html file, after all, not a js file).

Comment: Even with the addition of the '/' and the exclusion of content.js from the manifest, I was unable to get the page to forward when accessing http://www.google.com. I have updated the source of my files above to be more comprehensive (they now contain the entirety of the files' contents) and to remove superfluous items in the manifest. Does anything stand out in the above files that deviates from the version you created that is functional? I am really interested in getting this to work.

Comment: I've copied an pasted your exact contents and it works for me. I have only these two files in a folder, "background.html" and "manifest.json" and use the "Load unpacked extension" button from Chrome's Extension Preferences page to load that folder. Have you reloaded your extension after you made the changes?

Comment: I have reloaded the extension many times and have confirmed that there are only those two files in the folder. I have also generated the .crx file and loaded the extension onto other machines, still to no avail, so I think there is something wrong with the code, though I don't know what since it worked for you. Would it be possible to obtain your version of the above code? Thank you for the help.

Comment: Sure. I've uploaded it here: http://temp.regisgaughan.com/fwd_chrome_ext.zip Again, it just has the exact code you have changed above. Btw, I'm using Chrome 18.0.1003.1 dev if you want to check versions... if you're using an old version it's possible it doesn't have the API since it was experimental.

Comment: I presumed that the Chrome Extension docs described what was available in the latest stable release but this is not the case. When I upgraded to the dev release (18.x) from the stable (16.x), the extension worked as expected. Thank you for the help. If anyone else runs into this sort of issue, maybe they will see this thread and not have to endure the frustration that I experienced. :)

Comment: Does anyone know how to make this extension to go in the previous page if it joins lets say google.com as your example? Not to redirect, just to go to the previous page that you where.